How to flatten a list in a specific way
I have a list problem that I am struggling to come up with a solution for. Say we have the following list:
[0, 1, [2, 3], 4]
I want to pass this through a function and return two "flattened" versions of the list:
[0, 1, 2, 4] and [0, 1, 3, 4]
As a further example, the list [0, 1, [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]] should return 6 lists in total (total should be the multiplication of the length of each sub-list). You could think of the main list as a journey and the sub-lists as different routes along the way, each permutation tracking the different paths you could take through the main list.
How can I retrieve a list of each of these permutations? I suspect recursion might be involved but I cannot conceptualize it. If it helps each element in the list is unique (in this example int, but for my purposes each element will be a unique tuple i.e. (0, 0), (1,0) etc)
Below is what I have so far:
def func(lst, i=0):
    return_list = []
    for x in lst:
        if isinstance(x, tuple):
            return_list.append(x)
        else:
            return_list.append(x[i-1])
    return return_list

test_list = [(0, 0), (1, 0), [(1, 1), (2, 1)], (3, 0)]

for i in test_list:
    if isinstance(i, list):
        for j in range(len(i)):
            new_path = func(test_list, j)
            if new_path not in path_list:
                path_list.append(new_path)

#path_list = [[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 0)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (3, 0)]]

This code works for the simple case of [0, 1, [2, 3], 4] but only returns 3 results for an expanded case, i.e. [0, 1, [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], per below:
...
test_list = [(0, 0), (1, 0), [(1, 1), (2, 1)], [(3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2)]]
...
#path_list = [[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (3, 0)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 1)]]


Is there a limit to how deep the list nesting can go?

Check out this answer that uses itertools to achieve this with a list-of-lists. The input is ever-so-slightly different than yours, but I think this would do the trick for your usecase.

The trick is to make sure even the non-list elements are instead singleton lists ([[0], [1], [2, 3], [4]] instead of [0, 1, [2, 3], 4]).

@ScottHunter - Yes there can only be one sub-list within the main list. The tuple values above map onto a boggle board by index value, so there is a tuple for every location a character is on the board

But your example [0, 1, [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]] has two sub-lists.

To be clear, In terms of list nesting, only tuples can be in the sub-list. There can be multiple sublists in the main list.

How did you create those lists? Why are they like [0, 1, [2, 3], 4] instead of the more consistent and convenient [[0], [1], [2, 3], [4]]?

They are an illustration, take a look at the code

What am I supposed to see in the code? I only see such a list hard-coded there.

Then you can't help me

With thanks to @JNevill for the link to the answer, what I was looking for was the cartesian product of the lists. Solution below (eveything changed to singleton lists per @chepner):
def cartesian_product(ar_list):
if not ar_list:
    yield ()
else:
    for a in ar_list[0]:
        for prod in cartesian_product(ar_list[1:]):
            yield (a,)+prod

l = [[(0, 0)], [(1, 0)], [(1, 1), (2, 1)], [(2, 3), (3, 0), (1, 3)]]
print(list(cartesian_product(l)))
# [((0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 3)),((0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (3, 0)), ((0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 3)), ((0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 1), (2, 3)), ((0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 0)), ((0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 1), (1, 3))]


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
